# visualforce Mobile page and <select> HTML5 element render problems

Tags: jquery, html, select, salesforce, visualforce

when I create a visualforce page with HTML5 for Mobile select element, it adds unwanted  and  elements that ruin the page style. It also adding elements over the page, and underneath it.

for example - from this HTML code:

```
    <select id="status" placeholder="Status">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
            <option>Option 4</option>
     </select>
```

It creates this HTML code:

```
    <div class="ui-select">
        <div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data- wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-c">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">
                    <span>Option 1</span>
                </span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
            <select id="status" placeholder="Status">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
                <option>Option 4</option>
            </select>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I already tried adding on top the standardStylesheets="false" attribute, but it still doesn't help.

I know I can delete them using JQuery when the page loads, but I cant rely on this solution for the long term.

Is there another way to fix it? Disabling some of the visualforce rendering properties?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Those tags are added as part of the JQuery Mobile progressive enhancement rather than Visualforce.  The section above the select renders the first element with the down arrow (i.e. the large "January" in my screenshot below), while clicking on it (as I have) produces a select underneath.

[image]

If you remove these items, your select won't have the JQuery Mobile look and feel and it may mess up the updating of the selection.